# How to call the fear of no gravity?

Tags: gravity, astrophysics, orbital-mechanics, space, apparent-motion

In opposite to barophobia I can't google out a fear of the case, when a man is taken out of the ship and he must go through the spaceship's docks and he can't get the direction of gravity - in the manner phobic manner. Of course astronauts are tend to be out of the problem, but an ordinary man?
It's probably similar to the fear of height when someone looks up not down, while has a knowledge of being somewhere high up. Such passenger probably couldn't get from gate to gate in 3m high and 10m long space corridor - or maybe larger. Of course the case would be dramatic outside the ship, but probably a man would never get t
I can't feel it of course, but I stuck to find the proper name for this phobia. Astrophobia is something else of course.

I guess, the question might be moved somewhere, because tags are not very responsible for this case. I'd tag it like: space-motion, astro-psychology, zero-gravity, astronautics.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is an astronomy question, but one for the English language SE.

Comment: I would recommend that before resorting to English SE (where folks can often be very picky about the quality of previous research in a question being insufficient in their view) one consider migration to [Space Exploration SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/) where medical and psychological details of spaceflight are frequently discussed and those involved with spaceflight (and perhaps even a few who have done so personally) may chime in.

Comment: Related: https://xkcd.com/1115/ ;)

Comment: Probably classifiable under barophobia

Comment: I use temporary name - astrobarophobia